# underscore.js template error

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to load .txt file to `<div>` and when .txt have code like this

```
<h1>Hello <%= name %></h1>
```

It is working properly, but when I have some code like this

```
<select name="action_edit" id="task_action_edit">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <%
    foreach(actions as action) {
        if(action['id'] == 2) {
        %>
            <option selected="selected" value="<%= action['id'] %>" action_abbr="<%= action['title'] %>">
                <%= action['title'] %>
            </option>
        <%                                
        } else {
        %>
            <option value="<%= action['id'] %>" action_abbr="<%= action['title'] %>">
                <%= action['title'] %>
            </option>
        <%
        }
    }
    %>
</select>
```

Firefox showing me this error when I'm loading this .txt code to div

```
missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error] var __p=[],print=function(){__p.push.a... </select>');}return __p.join('');
underscore.js (line 779)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Underscore's templates](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) use JavaScript inside the `<% ... %>` delimiters. This:

```
foreach(actions as action) {
```

is not JavaScript and that could lead to the odd error you're seeing. Maybe you mean:

```
for(action in actions) {
```

in your template.

Comment: that was very silly mistake that I did. I wrote it like in php. Thanks,

Comment: @user616822: You're not the only one that gets their languages confused and that error message certainly wasn't very helpful.